# restsharp how to add key value pair as parameter

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, restsharp

I am trying to consume stripe.com api with restsharp, using the charge command

https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_charge

there's an opportunity to pass metadata as key value pairs but I don't seem to succeed

```
  const string baseUrl = "https://api.stripe.com/";
  const string endPoint = "v1/charges";
  var apiKey = this.SecretKey;

  var client = new RestClient(baseUrl) { Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(apiKey, "") };
  var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, Method.POST);

  request.AddParameter("card", token);
  request.AddParameter("amount", wc.totalToPayForStripe);
  request.AddParameter("currency", "eur");
  request.AddParameter("description", wc.crt.cartid + " - " + wc.co.oid);
  request.AddParameter("metadata", "{cartid: " + wc.crt.cartid + ", oid: " + wc.co.oid + "}");
  request.AddParameter("statement_description", "# " + wc.crt.cartid);
  request.AddParameter("description", wc.crt.cartid + " - " + wc.co.oid);
```

Always getting the following error:

```
Invalid metadata: metadata must be a set of key-value pairs
```

Clearly I don't pass the key value pair the way I should but I can't find any restsharp documentation on that.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
  const string baseUrl = "https://api.stripe.com/";
  const string endPoint = "v1/charges";
  var apiKey = this.SecretKey;

  var client = new RestClient(baseUrl) { Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(apiKey, "") };
  var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, Method.POST);

  request.AddParameter("card", token);
  request.AddParameter("amount", wc.totalToPayForStripe);
  request.AddParameter("currency", "eur");
  request.AddParameter("description", wc.crt.cartid + " - " + wc.co.oid);
  request.AddParameter("metadata[cartid]", wc.crt.cartid);
  request.AddParameter("metadata[oid]", wc.co.oid);
  request.AddParameter("statement_description", "# " + wc.crt.cartid);
  request.AddParameter("description", wc.crt.cartid + " - " + wc.co.oid);
```

For some reason HTTP Post requests can not accept key-value objects and must be sent in this type of format. This isn't a stripe restriction, but HTTP in general.

Comment: Worked for me too. Coding in a different language but same issue & solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's telling you to enter them as such:

```
request.AddParameter("metadata", "[ { cartid: " + wc.crt.cartid + "} ,{ oid: " + wc.co.oid + " }]" );
```

Comment: But RestSharp AddParamenter doesn't have that overload.